# Error trying to pass regex match to function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, syntax-error

I'm getting `Syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'`

This is the code i'm using

```
function wpse44503_filter_content( $content ) {
    $regex = '#src=("|\')'.
        '(/images/(19|20)(0-9){2}/(0|1)(0-9)/[^.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp|jpeg))'.
        '("|\')#';
    $replace = 'src="'.get_site_url( $2 ).'"';

    $output = preg_replace( $regex, $replace, $content );

    return $output;
}
```

This is the line where i'm getting that error `$replace = 'src="'.get_site_url( $2 ).'"';`

Can anyone help me to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: $2 is an invalid PHP variable name.... "A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores."

Comment: Are you trying to pass the second capture group `$2` into that function? (Interesting how many people seem to have missed this.)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes thats right. I'm trying to pass the second capture group into that function. What should i put there instead of `$2` ? Thanks

Comment: What capture group?  You haven't done a regex match (in the code that I can see) before the line `$replace = 'src="'.get_site_url( $2 ).'"';`.

Comment: @user1091558 I added an example of preg_replace_callback to my answer below, you'll need to use that function to be able to call functions on a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do (ie replacing the matched string with the result of a function call) can't be done using [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), you'll need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead to get a function called for every match.

A short example of preg_replace_callback;

```
$get_site_url =                    // Returns replacement
  function($row) { 
    return '!'.$row[1].'!';        // row[1] is first "backref"
  };                                                     

$str = 'olle';
$regex = '/(ll)/';                 // String to match

$output = preg_replace_callback(   // Match, calling get_site_url for replacement
    $regex,
    $get_site_url,
    $str);

var_dump($output);                 // output "o!ll!e"
```

Comment: So what does `T_LNUMBER` mean exactly?

Comment: @Pacerier `T_LNUMBER` means an integer (see [here](http://www.php.net/tokens) for a list). The parser is expecting to find a valid variable name or another `$` but finds the integer `2`. The reason is that `$2` is an illegal variable name, so the parser will show this message which basically means "unexpected integer found".

Comment: Everything starts with `T_`, does "T" mean "token"?

Answer (score 9):

You can't have '$2' as a variable name.  It must start with a letter or underscore.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

*Edit* Above was my original answer and is the correct answer to the simple "syntax error" question.  More in-depth answer below...

You are trying to use $2 to represent "the second capture group", but you haven't done anything at that point to match your regex.  Even if $2 was a valid PHP variable name, it still wouldn't be set at that point in your script.  Because of this, you can determine that you are using `preg_replace` improperly and that it may not suit your actual needs.

Note that the [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) documentation doesn't support using $n as a separate variable outside of the replacement operation.  In other words, `'foo' . $1 . 'bar'` is not a valid replacement string, but `'foo$1bar'` is.

Depending on the complexity of `get_site_url`, you have 2 options:

1. If `get_site_url` is simply adding a root directory or server name, you could change your replacement string to `src="/myotherlocation$2"`.  This will effectively replace "/image/..." with "/myotherlocation/image/..." in the img src.  This will not work if `get_site_url` is doing something more complex.
2. If `get_site_url` is complex, you should use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) per [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571634/364198).  Give the documentation a read and post a new question (or I guess update this question?) if you have trouble with the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

PHP variable names cant begin with a number.

Answer (score 3):

`$2` is not a valid PHP variable. If you meant the second group in the regex then you want to put `\2` in a string. However, since you're passing it to a function then you'll need to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead and substitute appropriately in the callback.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the second capture group into that function. How to put that `\2`. If you don't mind give me some sample code or can you give me the modified code of my function? Thanks

Comment: Hey there, Sorry.. You've mistaken me.  I'm a php beginner. I checked the link you provided. But it looks more advanced. Thats why i'm still asking your help.

Answer (score 0):

if PHP variable begins with number use following:

when I was getting the following as the result set from thrid party API

[image]

Code Works

```
$stockInfo->original->data[0]->close_yesterday
```

Code Failed

```
$stockInfo->original->data[0]->52_week_low
```

Solution

```
$stockInfo->original->data[0]->{'52_week_high'}
```