# preg_replace reuse matched value in replacement value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to perform value replacement based on matched value. The replacement expression has calculation based on matched value.

[regex](https://regex101.com/r/8PIsky/1)

```
<?php
 $re = '/<w:d([^\[]+)\/>/m';
 $str = '<w:d2/>';
 //$subst = "<w:ind w:left='.eval(\"return \".\"720*$1;\").' w:right=\"\"/>";
 $subst = "<w:ind w:left='".eval("return 720*$1;")."' w:right=\"\"/>";
 $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
 echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
?>
```

I want to multiply 720 with matched value an return it in string.

I got error :

> syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Get rid of evil eval, and use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: Yes, you are right. able to solve it using preg_replace_callback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shown because variable must start with letter or underscore. So,$1 could not use as variable. Using preg_replace_callback, I can call first captured value using matched array index 1. @Farray has gave detailed answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571559/error-trying-to-pass-regex-match-to-function)) related to this issues.

```
$result=preg_replace_callback($re, function($matches)
  {
    return "<w:ind w:left='".(720*$matches[1])."' w:right='".(720*$matches[1])."'/>";
  }, $str);
```